# mapping json data/object flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, mapping, httprequest

I'm super new in flutter.Could somebody help me map my json data from `HTTP request`. What I want to do is get only one column value on my json data which is the `sendto_id` and make condition to compare it with the `id` I've stored in `sharedpreferences`.
Here my code below.

```
 class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> { 
   int counter = 0;
   String id= "";

  getPref() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
       id = preferences.getString('id');
    });
  }

 

  Future getData() async {
    var url = 'http://10.20.35.1/school/fetch2.php';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    List data = json.decode(response.body);
    
    
     setState(() {
     counter= data.length;
    });
  }

    @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
    getPref();
    getData();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery
          .of(context)
          .size
          .width * 0.7,
      child: Drawer(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            children: <Widget>[
        
              ListTile(
                leading:  Container(
                height: 100,        
                width: 100,    
                
               child: new Stack(
          
                children: <Widget>[
                  
                Icon(Icons.announcement,color: Colors.cyan, size: 25.0),
                counter != 0 ? new Positioned(
                    left:22,
                    top: 0,
                 child: new Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                      ),
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        minWidth: 14,
                        minHeight: 14,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        '$counter',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 8,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    )
                  ) : new Container()
                ],
            
                ),  
                ),
              title: new GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => {
                  widget.onTap(context, 1),
                  setState(() {
                      counter = 0;
                    }),
                },
                child: Text("Announcements",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
```

These are the json datas which I've fetched from my database.

`[{"type":"Assault","sendto_id":"12"}]`

`[{"type":"Rape","sendto_id":"9"}]`

`[{"type":"Assault","sendto_id":"4"}]`

`[{"type":"Theif","sendto_id":"12"}]`

The code is working, but  `$counter` variable count it as 4 datas since I have not made a condition yet. I want to make condition with  `sharedprefences` data `id` which is 12 but I dont know how to do it.So, what I expected here is `$counter` variable would count 2 datas only after the condition would be done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way. listbuilder, map function ...

```
   ListView.builder(
                itemCount: counter,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return data[index].sendto_id"==12?text("this 
                :12"):text(data[index].sendto_id);
              })
```

--------or--------

```
    data.map((element) {
        return element.sendto_id"==12?text("this :12"):text(element.sendto_id);;
    }).toList();
```